# Start directions app from Windows Phone HTML5 App

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I have an App that show a location in a Google Map in HTML and I'd like to start an navigation app (Google Maps, Bing Maps, Nokia Here, ...) when I touch the map. Is there a way to start an installed navigation/directions app from HTML5 with a specified destination location?

I found the [ms-drive-to URI-Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj710324(v=vs.105).aspx), but the mobile Internet Explorer stats that this URI-Scheme is not supportet.

Is there any other way, or do I have to somehow get an event from the HTML5-side of my app to the C#-side and create a [MapsTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206989(v=vs.105).aspx) there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up too quickly.

Turns out the [ms-drive-to URI-Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj710324(v=vs.105).aspx) is working after all, unless you enter it in the navigation bar directly.

So using it from a link, form, window.location or window.open is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only adding this as an answer, on the chance that it might work.  Because, I honestly don't know.  I've tested it on all manner of Android and iPhone, but not Windows:

```
<form action="http://maps.google.com/maps" method="get" target="_blank">        
        <input type="hidden" name="saddr" id="address" />
        <input type="hidden" name="daddr" value="400 Mercer St, Hightstown, NJ 08520" />
        <input type="submit" value="Get Directions" class="menubarBut" style="height: 32px;width: 110px;font-size: 12px;line-height: 12px;margin-top: 5px;" />
    </form>
```

The idea here is that form submits the address.  The device intercepts the call and asks what you want to do with it, Google maps, GPS, Navigator, etc...

Like I said...  This works all over the place so far.  And as near as I can tell it's as close as I've found to a universal solution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and report back.

Comment: That's what I'm hoping, actually.  Since I have no way of testing it, I'd like to hear how it goes.

Comment: No, it's not working. At least not without installed Google Maps app, I'll try that next, just for closure, but either way it's not an accaptable sulution.

Comment: You did! I tried to put the ms-drive-to URI in the form and it started the app. The URL-Scheme does work when you navigate to it from a link or a form, it's just not working when you enter it in the navigation bar.